# TYPO3 backend rendering very long on server which has limited access to internet

Tags: typo3

I am building intranet with TYPO3 and I am on machine where firewall is blocking all external traffic. I have strange behaviour. Rendering of TYPO3 backend takes exactly 60 sec. Its only about rendering main window. The navigation inside Web->page, Web->list is very fast.
I figured out that this value 60sec can be lowered by setting in LocalConfiguration.php a `['HTTP']['timeout']`. I set also `['HTTP']['verify']` to false to exclude some SSL issues but it did not helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On first backend rendering TYPO3 checks if the current TYPO3 version is actively maintained and if not it shows message to user. As maintain period can be changed TYPO3 core decided to fetch the information from external url https://get.typo3.org/v1/api/major/9

The only solution without modifying core of TYPO3 is to disable part of TYPO3 backend that shows information that needs the external data:

`unset($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['toolbarItems'][1435433110]);`

This part is responsible about general technical info in top of toolbar. 
All information from this disabled part is also available in AdminTool->Environment.

Comment: IMHO the TYPO3 BE should work work fine without network. I would appreciate it if you could file a feature request or bug report to make this configurable. Thanks for narrowing this down. https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core/issues